# PHPExcel Truncate zero from begin and change dot in comma

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to create this excel with the A column setted as TEXT. In this column there will be some code product like:
0301.001.010
0301.006
the problem is that in the excel i get:

0301.001.010 ------> Ok (_dataType = 's')

301,006 -------> no,(_dataType = 'n') the  dot became a comma and there's not anymore the zero on the beginning

Right now I am using the version 1.7.8
I can change the version, but I can't find a good solution on google. Someone could help me with this problem?

Comment: Then use `setCellValueExplicit()` to ensure that the value is stored as a string datatype

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you! The problem was that I was using fromArray to print out the data, so like this i wasn0t able to set the datatype!

Comment: An alternative would be to use a custom binder, or upgrade to a more recent version of PHPExcel that has a stricter check for numeric values in the default binder